# How to group several requests to be sent with the same var in JMETER

Tags: java, jmeter

i'm struggling in finding a solution to my prob.
i created a program, that receive a var from db and execute requests using this var. this is how it looks:

- Beanshell assertion returns the var

  - while loop

    - Random controller

      - Simple Controller(1)

        - request 1
        - request 2
      - Simple  Controller(2)

        - request 1
        - request 2

it worked fine until now, means that all the requests under the chosen Simple controller were made with the same chosen var.
i tried to add something new, and the beanshell assertion to returns list, and to create another beanshell assertion inside the while loop which returns specific value from this list, so now it looks the same but with another beanshell insdide the while loop.
the problem now, is that not all the requests under the simple controller is executed with the same that returned in the beanshell under the while loop.

anyone have the idea how to fix it?

thanks.